# How to select all rows with max values in a derived table?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, derived-table

I have the following table called "table3"

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| aaa  |
| aaa  |
| aaa  |
| aaa  |
| aaa  |
| aaa  |
| bbb  |
| bbb  |
| bbb  |
| bbb  |
| ccc  |
| ccc  |
| ccc  |
| ccc  |
| ccc  |
| ccc  |
| ccc  |
| ccc  |
| ccc  |
+------+
```

when I got count for each name, I got

```
mysql>select name,count(name) as count from table3 group by name order by name;
+------+-------+
| name | count |
+------+-------+
| aaa  |     6 |
| bbb  |     4 |
| ccc  |     9 |
+------+-------+
```

so I ran the following query to return and names and max count net to them

```
mysql> select name from (select name,count(name) as count from table3 group by name order by name) as tbl where tbl.count=(select max(count) from tbl);
```

expecting the following result

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| ccc  |
+------+
```

but I get this error

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'tests.tbl' doesn't exist
```

Ihave done aliasing correctly, but the table alias "tbl" isn't identified in the part ".....unt=(select max(count) from tbl)"

then I used this queries too

```
mysql> select name from (select name,count(name) as count from table3 group by name order by name) as tbl where tbl.count=(select max(count) from tbl) as tb1;

mysql> select name from (select name,count(name) as count from table3 group by name order by name) as tbl where tbl.count=((select max(count) from tbl) as tb1);   //extra couple of parenthesis
```

they also give some different errors. Nothing was succeeded

How to fix this problem **without deriving another table from the original table (table3)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limit`:

```
select name
from t
group by name
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

If there can be ties and you want all values in that case, then use `rank()`:

```
select name
from (select name, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by name
     ) n
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Ah sorry, i didn't get the second part of your answer before. Thank you